# GoogleAdMobAds in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, google-ads-api

I had imported libGoogleAdMobAds.a and Adsupport framework in my projects.
and all header files.Linker flag as :- -0bjC.Architecture is armv7.
Xcode:- 4.5.2 and ios 4.3 and above.

But still it gives me the below error:-

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_CGSizeFromGADAdSize", referenced from:
          -[BannerExampleViewController viewDidLoad] in BannerExampleViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in BannerExampleViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADRequest", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in BannerExampleViewController.o
      "_kGADAdSizeBanner", referenced from:
          -[BannerExampleViewController viewDidLoad] in BannerExampleViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps you have to take:

1. In Build Setting, go for Linking. In this, you will find "other linker flags." Set -Objc for build and release.
2. You will be initializing the Admob with the defined rect. Consider: `AbMod = [GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,430,320,50)];`

Answer (score 1):

for anyone who is getting this problem 
see if you are missing this file: libGoogleAdMobAds.a

its solve my problem.

idan m.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

pls check the above url and download latest google sdk and try one's

note:have u add IAD framework to ur project

Answer (score 0):

I feel its the .a static library build problem.
You can find admob working example of AdBannerView is [here](http://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/BannerExample_iOS_2.7.zip). So compare your settings with it. And Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/). I worked on it and is working fine.